# Confusion regarding express server and nodejs http server

Tags: node.js, express

I am learning redis and in the docs they have the following server setup:

```
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

server.listen(80);

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
  socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

As you can see they are creating the express server on the first line which is what I usually do, but then they pass express to server = require('http') which I'm guessing is a node module for an http server.

Where I'm usually doing something like this:

```
const express = require('express')
const routes = require('./routes')

api.use('/', routes)

// Fireup up API server
api.listen(9090, () => {
  debug('API server listening on port 9090...')
})
```

Why in the first example express is being passed to the nodejs http module?

**EDIT**
I understand that the line `var server = require('http').Server(app)` is so we can later pass the server to socket.io using `var io = require('socket.io')(server);` What I don't understand is: 
**what is that 'http' module?
where does it come from?
how is it different from the express server?**

My second example I've supplied was from an api backend server that uses the api prefix for calls and that's why it had the '/api', I've only included it to demonstrate how I'm usually setting up a server and to show  that I'm not using `require('http').Server(app);` in the process.

**Edit2**
An additional question based on the answer and comments.
why do we need the extra step to pass the sever to the socket.io and not just pass the express server directly?

Comment: Hint: in your second snippet, where the `api` came from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first one is mounting the Express application to a new HTTP Server Instance that is also listening with Socket.io for socket connections. This is one of the ways you can create an Express Server that has Socket.io running with it.

Here's the [`socket.io` docs](https://socket.io/docs/#using-with-express-3/4) with the same Express and HTTP module usage as the example code.

The [HTTP module](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/http.html) is part of the Node Core API, so its just part of node. You can require it whenever within a node application. Express is built using the `http` module and wraps `http.Server`. So HTTP and Express are different in that Express builds upon the `http.Server` class and adds things like middleware, view engines, etc.

If you don't need the `socket.io` piece then you can just get rid of that, just like in your second code example. However, not sure where the `api` express instance came from in that snippet.

```
const express = require('express')
const routes = require('./routes')
const server = express()
const port = process.env.PORT || 1337

server.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

server.use('/api', routes)
server.listen(port, () => { console.log(`Listening on ${port}`) })
```

Comment: I understand that the line var server = require('http').Server(app) is so we can later pass the server to socket.io using var io = require('socket.io')(server); What I don't understand is what it that 'http' module where does it come from and how is it different from the express server?

Comment: So even though we are passing express to the http server like so var server = require('http').Server(app); it's actualls express that adds all the middlware ect. So why do we need the extra step can't we just pass express to the io like so: var io = require('socket.io')(app);

Comment: Because, `socket.io` is expecting an instance of `http.Server`. Express just wraps `http.Server` it is not an `http.Server` instance directly. Look at the [`socket.io Server docs`](https://socket.io/docs/server-api/#server). You're asking questions in addition to the original one that could easily be answered by just looking at the socket.io docs