# Routing and Requests in NodeJS Explained

Tags: node.js, express, http, axios

I've been trying to wrap my head around REST APIs using NodeJS. I would just like clarification on the subject.

So am I right in thinking that Express is used for setting up routers/endpoints while node packages such as Request, Axios, Got & node-fetch are used for making request to these routers?

And are all these packages (including Express) just wrappers using the HTTP/HTTPS core module that comes with node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Express is built using the http module and wraps http.Server. So HTTP
> and Express are different in that Express builds upon the http.Server
> class and adds things like middleware, view engines, etc.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44781787/9317057)

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply and the info regarding Express but is my general understanding on routers/request correct?

Comment: Yeah, you're right. Routers are responsible for processing the requests to the determined endpoints while Request/Axios etc provide the functionality to make these requests.